# iOS Copy Bundle to XCFramework

Tags: ios, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, xcframework

I am working on a Kotlin Multiplatform project currently. We are using Moko Resources (https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-resources) to create a shared directory of resources. This works great with FAT Frameworks, however we have a requirement to use XCFrameworks. I'm not very familiar with iOS and the framework situation, so forgive my ignorance.

Right now it seems something is going wrong when we build our XCFramework, as running the app shows a commainMain.MR is not available, so I think our bundle is not being copied correctly.

Here is our **fatFramework** Gradle task:

```
        register("buildFatFrameworkWithResources", TestFatFramework::class) {
        val debugMode = "DEBUG"
        val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: debugMode
        destinationDir = buildDir.resolve("xcode-universal-framework")
        group = "Universal framework"
        description = "Builds a universal (fat) $mode framework"

        from(iosArm64Framework, iosX64Framework)
        dependsOn(iosArm64Framework.linkTask)
        dependsOn(iosX64Framework.linkTask)
    }
```

And our **XCFramework** task

```
        register("buildXcFrameworkWithResources") {
        dependsOn("deleteXcFramework")
        val mode = "DEBUG"
        val frameworks = arrayOf("iosArm64", "iosX64").map {
            kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(it).binaries.getFramework(mode)
        }

        inputs.property("mode", mode)
        dependsOn(frameworks.map { it.linkTask })
        group = "Universal framework"
        description = "Builds a universal (xc) $mode framework"

        frameworks.first().outputFile.listFiles()
            ?.asSequence()
            ?.filter { it.name.contains(".bundle") }
            ?.forEach { bundleFile ->
                project.copy {
                    from(bundleFile)
                    into("$xcFrameworkPath/${bundleFile.name}")
                }
            }

        doLast {
            val buildArgs: () -> List<String> = {
                val arguments = mutableListOf("-create-xcframework")
                frameworks.forEach {
                    arguments += "-framework"
                    arguments += "${it.outputDirectory}/${project.name}.framework"
                }
                arguments += "-output"
                arguments += xcFrameworkPath
                arguments
            }

            exec {
                executable = "xcodebuild"
                args = buildArgs()
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not too sure what needs to be changed to make it work correctly.
Appreciate any help!

Comment: While I'm not sure if the original question is still relevant, I just want to inform any future readers that kotlin-multiplatform plugin now has the ability to build XCFrameworks. See details [in the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-build-native-binaries.html#build-xcframeworks).

Answer (score 2):

As @ArtyomDegtyarev just mentioned in the comments, you can directly build `XCFramework` by adding a Run script under the Build Phase of Xcode.

To do so:

- Open Xcode.
- Select the very first file (YourApp.xcodeproj).
- Select your target on the left and go to build phase on the right.
- Click on the + sign on the top left and select new run script phase.
- Insert this script :

  ```
  "$SRCROOT/../gradlew" -p "$SRCROOT/../" :shared:copyFrameworkResourcesToApp \
   -Pmoko.resources.PLATFORM_NAME=$PLATFORM_NAME \
   -Pmoko.resources.CONFIGURATION=$CONFIGURATION \
   -Pmoko.resources.BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR=$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR \
   -Pmoko.resources.CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH=$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH\
   -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.platform=$PLATFORM_NAME \
   -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.configuration=$CONFIGURATION \
   -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.cflags="$OTHER_CFLAGS" \
   -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.paths.headers="$HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" \
   -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.paths.frameworks="$FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS"
  ```
- Mind the name of your shared module. In my project it is called "shared". Replace with yours if different.

Now build and run, you should be able to access your shared resource.